# Can we use Composite Primary Key Mapping in spring data elastic search

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, composite-key

I have an entity 'Product' and I want the primary key in ES to be used as a combination of 'id' and 'name' attributes. How can we do that using spring data elastic search.

```
public class Product {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Id
    private String name;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private Category category;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Long)
    private double price;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Object)
    private List<ValidAge> age;

    public enum Category {
        CLOTHES,
        ELECTRONICS,
        GAMES;
    }
}
```

Comment: an id in Elasticsearch is always a String; so to have something like a composite id, Spring Data Elasticsearch would need to somehow merge `id` and `name` into a single String. But what do you want to achieve with this?

Comment: Basically, according to my use case, the combination of id and name (say id_name) is unique and I want to use it as the primary key of Elastic Search without having any attribute named id_name. Is that possible in elastic search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be the following:

- first rename your `id` property, I changed it to `documentId` here. This is necessary, because in Spring Data
  Elasticsearch an id-property can be either annotated with `@Id` or it can be namend `id`. As there can only be one
  id-property we need to get this out of the way. It can have the name *id* in Elasticsearch, set by the `@Field`
  annotation, but the Java property must be changed.
- second, add a method annotated with `@Id` and  `@AccessType(AccessType.Type.PROPERTY)` which returns the value you
  want to use in Elasticsearch.
- third, you need to provide noop-setter for this property. This is necessary because Spring Data Elasticsearchsoe
  not check the id property to be read only when populating an entity after save or when reading from the index.
  This is a bug in Spring Data Elasticsearch, I'll create an issue for that

So that comes up with an entity like this:

```java
@Document(indexName = "composite-entity")
public class CompositeEntity {

    @Field(name="id", type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String documentId;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String name;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String text;

    @Id
    @AccessType(AccessType.Type.PROPERTY)
    public String getElasticsearchId() {
        return documentId + '-' + name;
    }

    public void setElasticsearchId(String ignored) {
    }

    // other getter and setter
}
```

The repository definition would be straight forward:

```java
public interface CompositeRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<CompositeEntity,
    String> {
}
```

Remember that for every method that needs an Elasticsearch Id, you'll need to create like it's done in the entity
class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked fine except that I was getting ElasticsearchId as an attribute in my result. So, I used @JsonIgnore annotation to hide it.

Comment: Sure; but that's a problem of the REST layer, not of Spring Data Elasticsearch  ☺️

Comment: This 'elasticsearchId' field appears in the document. Is there a way and sense to exclude it from the document ? because it is computed

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about spring data elasticsearch but spring jpa provides the facility of defining composite primary key by using **@IdClass** where we can define a separate class(let us say class A) in which we can define all the fields which we want to be a part of composite key Then we can use **@IdClass(A.class)** in entity class and use @Id annotation on all the fields which should be the part of the composite key

you can refer to this article, although I am not sure whether the same concept will be applicable for spring data es - https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-composite-primary-keys

Comment: it is not working for spring data es

Comment: ohh, then i had no idea man